# How to enable google map service

Tags: android, geocoding

I had the problem that `geocoder.ispresent()` always returns `false`. I googled for the solution and found that google map service is not enabled. How we can enable that service? Can anyone guide me?

```
package com.incv.mobile.freejscf;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class MyApplication extends Application implements LocationListener {
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();       
        Location mLocation = null;
        if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                (new GetAddressTask(this)).execute(mLocation);
            }
        else{
            Log.e("Not", "Geocoder is not present");
        }

    }

    private class GetAddressTask extends
    AsyncTask<Location, Void, String> {
    Context mContext;
    public GetAddressTask(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Get a Geocoder instance, get the latitude and longitude
     * look up the address, and return it
     *
     * @params params One or more Location objects
     * @return A string containing the address of the current
     * location, or an empty string if no address can be found,
     * or an error message
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder =
                new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        // Get the current location from the input parameter list
        Location loc = params[0];
        // Create a list to contain the result address
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            /*
             * Return 1 address.
             */
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity",
                "IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return ("IO Exception trying to get address");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
        // Error message to post in the log
        String errorString = "Illegal arguments " +
                Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) +
                " , " +
                Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) +
                " passed to address service";
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString);
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return errorString;
        }
        // If the reverse geocode returned an address
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            // Get the first address
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            /*
             * Format the first line of address (if available),
             * city, and country name.
             */
            String addressText = String.format(
                    "%s, %s, %s",
                    // If there's a street address, add it
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ?
                            address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    // Locality is usually a city
                    address.getLocality(),
                    // The country of the address
                    address.getCountryName());
            // Return the text
            return addressText;
        } else {
            return "No address found";
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String address) {
       // mAddress.setText(address);
        Log.e("Address", address.toString());
    }

    }
    public void getAddress(View v) {
    // Ensure that a Geocoder services is available

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

In the above code first onCreate methid get executed. but it always goes into else part. It means GeoCoder.isProvider() return false.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? How do you get the geocoder and have you completed all the steps of the developer's guide on geocoder API?

Comment: @lvan ok i all post the code.

Comment: Are you running this on a device or emulator? Also, if you comment the condition and execute the task regardless of what `isPresent()` returns, does the rest of the code fail at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the developers guide for setting up map in android apps.
Following is a quick guide line

1. Download the google playservices from android sdk manager
2. Add this to eclipse and add this as library for your project
3. Add your keys and other prerequisties inside google console
4. Embed the necessary permissions and keys inside AndroidManifest.xml